# Spring Boot Parent and Spring Cloud starter gateway version issue

Tags: spring-boot

I am forced to use/mention Spring cloud gateway version because my organization uses nexus repo.
I am using spring boot parent version 2.5.12, could you please let me know which version of spring
cloud starter gateway should I use. I have tried 3.x.x version for gateway but no use.

Comment: Use Spring Boot version `2.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Compatibility Matrix in the below

Check for **Release train Spring Boot compatibility** in the below

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Answer (score 0):

See compatible version between Spring Cloud (Spring Cloud Gateway) with Spring Boot at here. https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/27/spring-cloud-2021-0-3-is-available-compatible-with-spring-boot-2-7-0

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki

Choose correct versions pair for you.

For example: `Spring Cloud Gateway 3.1.3` (belong to `Spring Cloud 2021.0.3 Release Train`) works with `Spring Boot 2.6.x` and `Spring Boot 2.7.x`

[image]